# Replace <li> index value with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, replace, html-lists

I am working on an interactive web page that involves the use of an un-ordered list. What I want is that, whenever a user clicks on an element in that list, whether it be the first child or the tenth, that element becomes the first child.
I have figured out a few ways to find the index value of the `<li>` being clicked, but I havent been able to find a way to replace that element's index value.
This seems like a question that should have been asked before, but I combed through a bunch of image and element slideshows, and all they do is scroll through or fade content in and out of a lightbox, which is not even close to what I'm after.
Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`prepend` moves element as a first child to a selector

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

so you could do:

```
$('li').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().prepend($(this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3hLk7/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you guys, I will have to comb over the API and see what else I've been missing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery's [prependTo](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).

http://jsfiddle.net/9CFm9/

```
$('li').click( function() {
     $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
});
```